# SQLite "file is encrypted or is not a database"

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, encryption

I guess this should be fairly simple, since I an new to Xcode, Objective-C and SQLite, and I am just trying to get a simple tutorial to work.

I copied the "sampled.sql" file to the directory and this is the code that connects:

```
-(NSMutableArray *) authorList {
theauthors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
@try {
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sampledb.sql"];
    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

    }

    const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM verb";

    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement 1:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    } else {

        while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            Author * author = [[Author alloc] init];
            author.verb_nutid = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,1)];
            //author.title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,2)];
            [theauthors addObject:author];
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement 2:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
@finally {
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return theauthors;
}
```

}

DATABASE FILE:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

CREATE TABLE "verb" ('ID' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 'verba' TEXT, 'verbb' TEXT);
INSERT INTO 'verb' VALUES …

And so on...

But I get the error:

Problem with prepare statement 1:  file is encrypted or is not a database

Help would be much appreciated! (-:

Comment: give me ur mail-id i am sending u code @user4030788

Comment: You can not write to a file in an app and the mainBundle resourcePath is in the app.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your replies! I will try mr. Erzékiels suggestion somehow... (-:

Comment: I only want to read the database file! I really tried to research this on the internet, and there should be no problem placing the db file in the bundle, as long as Im not gonna change it.

Comment: Did the file open? There is a problem with the code in that if the file can not be opened it continues on read the db. You need to either do an early return on exists or open failure or skip the rest of the code after a failure occurs. Question: did the file exist? did it open?

Comment: That's a good point. It seems to pass the "fileExistsAtPath" since there is no "cannot locate database file"-message. To me it looks like  the error occurs with the sqlite3_prepare. And there I'm stuck...

Answer (score 1):

Try to write your `sampledb.sql` into the `documents directory` instead of the `bundle directory` :

```
// Getting the documents directory path
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

// Getting your db's path
NSString *dbPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sampledb.sql"];
```

There's no way to write into the bundle directory because it's code signed with SSL certificate. But the documents directory's not.

Comment: Okay... well, I tried your code and now I got this... Cannot locate database file '/Users/anker/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/5F97A08C-0F99-45C7-939C-00514CFC84FD/Documents/sampledb.sql'.
2014-09-11 22:32:17.647 TheDBproject[7691:60b] Problem with prepare statement 1:  no such table: verb

Comment: Oh sorry - I dont get it no... I only want to read the database file! I really tried to research this on the internet, and there should be no problem placing the db file in the bundle, as long as Im not gonna change it. So the problem remains - why cant I read the db file with the code above?

Comment: The above code seems correct, but why do you absolutely want to write the database file in the bundle ? The document directory is precisely here to store the app related files. Try `sampledb.db` instead of `sampledb.sql`. If it doesn't work at all, did you put some breakpoints to inspect variables values ?

Comment: Well, honestly I dont care where the database file is, as long as it works (I'm just trying to do what the tutorial is teaching me :-) … But the path your code shows me doesn't seem to exist on my computer (when I search manually there is no path "users/anker/library/application support/..."), so I cant really place the db file there.

Comment: I tried putting in some breakpoints, and without any changes it suddenly stopped with the "cannot locate db file"?? Well, thats great, somehow… Now it's just saying "no such table: verb". So now I pasted the first code from the sql file, that shows the 'verb' table, as far as I can see. Maybe it's the sql file there is something wrong with?

Comment: This is not really the answer to my problem, but in case anyone else should have similar problems, I used the above code (Erzekiels), dirPaths, to place the database in the documents directory, which I couldnt find, because the path is somehow not visible as default on my computer (Mavericks). In Finder I pressed "command + shift + G" and pasted the path from the NSLog (dirPaths) and thats how I found the db file. Now I can edit the db file and both read (and write). Thanks for your help, everyone! :-)